# jquery ui tabs content print on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

```
  function printDiv(divId) {
        //Get the HTML of div
        var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;

        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

        //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
        document.body.innerHTML =
          "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" +
          divElements + "</body>";

        //Print Page
        window.print();

        //Restore orignal HTML
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;

    }
```

first tab's div content  is printed using above function, but i have multiple tabs and print it on single button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a jquery plugin to print the content inside a div. Look [here](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use CSS for printing ? CSS is very powerfull for that: you can define  tags where you set display="none" for all but the body, and those tags will only apply for print and print preview. It's quite simpler no ?

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-print/) you've a perfect exemple of CSS for printing: